# How to initialize a multidimensional array in c++?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I want to make an array and set values to it some what like this `double MyArray[][] = {{0.1,0.8},{0.4,0.6},{0.3,0.9}}`. I don't however want to do this `MyArray[0][0] = 0.1; MyArray[0,1] = 0.8; MyArray[1][0] = 0.4;`ect, But I don't know how to do this. Thanks in advance for any help :) .

Answer (score 3):

It is enough to write

```
double MyArray[][2] = {{0.1,0.8},{0.4,0.6},{0.3,0.9}};
                ^^^
```

A two-dimensional array is a one-dimensional array elements of which are in turn arrays. When an array is created the size of its elements shall be known.

You can imagine this the following way

```
typedef double T[2];

//..

T MyArray[] = {{0.1,0.8},{0.4,0.6},{0.3,0.9}};
```

As for these statements

```
MyArray[0][0] = 0.1; MyArray[0,1] = 0.8; MyArray[1][0] = 0.4;
```

then if you would declare the array like this

```
#include <array>

//...

std::array<double, 2> MyArray[3];
```

You could write

```
MyArray[0] = { 0.1, 0.8 };
MyArray[1] = { 0.4, 0.6 };
MyArray[2] = { 0.3, 0.9 };
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to at least tell the compiler what the inner dimension is:

```
double MyArray[][2] = {{.1, .8},{.4, .6} /* etc... */ };
```